# Convert ProperCase to a sentence which is in Title Case (as opposed to sentence case)

Tags: c#

Hello I'd like to convert a word which is in proper case to a sentence which is in title case. Example:

`NumberOfLoyalHonestWomen` would become

> Number Of Loyal Honest Women

It's basically a way combined with reflection to turn Field / Property names into poor man's labels when auto-generating the inputs for a screen.

Here's what I got. Is there a better or cleaner way?
[Dot Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vSZiQI)

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string testString = "ATCPConnection";
        Console.WriteLine(testString.ToSentence());
    }

}

public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string ToSentence(this string Source)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(string.Concat(from Char c 
                                           in Source.ToCharArray()
                                           select Char.IsUpper(c) ? " " + c : c.ToString()).Trim(), 
                             "(?<AcronymLetter>[A-Z]) (?=[A-Z](?![a-z]))", 
                             "${AcronymLetter}");
    }

}
```

Side Note: It was complicated by my desire to keep acronyms intact, hence the `Regex.Replace`. For example:

`MGTOWSaysThereAreMoreUnicorns` would become

> MGTOW Says There Are More Unicorns

Comment: With your algorithm, how would you expect it to handle `ATCPConnecton`?

Comment: @MagikM18, ATCP Connecton

Comment: Yes, but that would look weird to the user when the correct sentence might be A TCP Connection. I'm not sure how important this is to you, but it's worth thinking about

Comment: That's true, it would look weird. Property / Field names starting with the participle A or the pronoun I will come out messed up and I'll have to avoid Property / Field names like that if I want good labels with this algorithm. +1 your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's another approach:

1. Insert a space before every uppercase letter which is immediately **followed** by a lowercase letter (except if this occurs at the beginning of the string). This adds spaces before PascalCased words.
2. Then insert a space before every uppercase letter which is immediately **preceded** by a lowercase letter. This adds spaces before ACRONYMS.

Thus:

```
public static string ToSentence(this string Source)
{
    Source = Regex.Replace(Source, "((?<!^)[A-Z][a-z])", " $1");
    Source = Regex.Replace(Source, "([a-z])([A-Z])", "$1 $2");
    return Source;
}
```

**UPDATE:** The two regexes above can be combined into a one-liner:

```
public static string ToSentence(this string Source)
{
    return Regex.Replace(Source, "(?<!^)[A-Z][a-z]|(?<=[a-z])[A-Z]", " $0");
}
```

Comment: Visualization: `VisitorsOnFLAGDay`. Step 1: `Visitors OnFLAG Day`. Step 2: `Visitors On FLAG Day`. Done.

Comment: Impressive. Direct. Simple. I used this; but I just returned straight from the second line and cut out one line of code.

Comment: Thanks. I might use this question for interviews. :-)

Comment: Nice. Another possibility for the first line is `Regex.Replace(Source, "(.)([A-Z][a-z])", "$1 $2");`

Answer (score 3):

How about this implementation?

FYI: `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute` cannot be used in C#.
(It can be used in VB.NET.)

Mark the method's first parameter with the `this` keyword instead.

```
public static string ToSentence(this string value)
{
    char[] characters = value.ToCharArray();

    // Determine where groups start
    List<int> groupStartIndexes =
        characters
            .Select((character, index) =>
                new
                {
                    Character = character,
                    Index = index
                }
            )
            .Where(obj => Char.IsUpper(obj.Character))
            .Select(obj => obj.Index)
            .ToList();

    // if there is no upper case letter or
    // if value does not start with an upper case letter
    if (!groupStartIndexes.Contains(0))
    {
        groupStartIndexes.Insert(0, 0);
    }

    // To make our life easier
    groupStartIndexes.Add(value.Length);

    var groups = new List<string>();

    // Split value into groups
    for (int index = 0; index < groupStartIndexes.Count - 1; index++)
    {
        int currentGroupStartIndex = groupStartIndexes[index];
        int nextGroupStartIndex = groupStartIndexes[index + 1];

        string currentGroup =
            value
                .Substring(
                    currentGroupStartIndex,
                    nextGroupStartIndex - currentGroupStartIndex
                );

        groups.Add(currentGroup);
    }

    var sb = new StringBuilder(groups[0]);

    // Build the final string
    for (int currentGroupIndex = 1; currentGroupIndex < groups.Count; currentGroupIndex++)
    {
        string previousGroup = groups[currentGroupIndex - 1];
        string currentGroup = groups[currentGroupIndex];

        if (previousGroup.Length > 1 || currentGroup.Length > 1)
        {
            sb.Append(" ");
        }

        sb.Append(groups[currentGroupIndex]);
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I like your implementation because it avoids any `using` statement. Also, it is probably faster. I'll put both our algorithms in a .Net Fiddle and get the times. Thanks! +1

Comment: They come out the same speed. See my fiddle.

Comment: This algorithm doesn't handle embedded or trailing acronyms. For example, `"MGTOWSaysThereAREMoreUNICORNS".ToSentence()` returns `"MGTOW Says ThereARE MoreUNICORN S"`.

Comment: @MichaelLiu I updated my answer based on your comment.

Comment: Now it returns `"MGTOW Says  There ARE More UNICORN S"`.

Comment: @MichaelLiu You're right. I completely rewrote the method. Now it should work as expected. I updated my answer with the new solution.

Comment: +1. Note that an exception is thrown if the input doesn't contain any uppercase letters. (The OP stated that the input is a word in Proper Case, so this might not be an issue.)

Comment: @MichaelLiu True. :) I updated my answer to avoid exception.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like an interesting topic. Here is my attempt.

```
public static string ToSentence(this string src) {
    var retVal = "";
    if (src.Length > 0) {
        List<string> wordCollection = new List<string>();
        int startIndex = 0;
        char[] letters = src.ToCharArray();
        //Skip the First Letter
        var length = letters.Length;
        for (int i = 1; i < length; i++) {
            if (char.IsUpper(letters[i])) {
                //Check for acronyms
                if (char.IsUpper(letters[i - 1])
                    && (
                           i == length - 1 ||
                           ((i + 1) < length && (char.IsUpper(letters[i + 1]) || char.IsNumber(letters[i + 1])))
                        )
                )
                    continue;

                //Grab Eeverything before Current Index
                var temp = new String(letters, startIndex, i - startIndex);
                wordCollection.Add(temp.Trim());
                startIndex = i;
            }
        }
        wordCollection.Add(new String(letters, startIndex, letters.Length - startIndex));
        retVal = String.Join(" ", wordCollection);
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

The following tests all pass

```
   public class TestCases {
        [DataDrivenTestMethod]
        [DataRow("NumberOfLoyalHonestWomen", "Number Of Loyal Honest Women")]
        [DataRow("MGTOWSaysThereAreMoreUnicorns", "MGTOW Says There Are More Unicorns")]
        [DataRow("MGTOW1SaysThereAreMoreUnicorns", "MGTOW1 Says There Are More Unicorns")]
        [DataRow("MGTOWSaysThereAreMOREUnicorns", "MGTOW Says There Are MORE Unicorns")]
        [DataRow("MGTOWSaysThereAREMoreUNICORNS", "MGTOW Says There ARE More UNICORNS")]            
        public void ConvertToTitleCase(string stringUnderTest, string expected) {
            var actual = stringUnderTest.ToSentence();
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Voted up for reinforcing that there are indeed more unicorns

Comment: Close: `"MGTOWSaysThereAREMoreUNICORNS"` returns `"MGTOW Says There ARE More UNICORN S"`, with an extra space before the final S.

Comment: @MichaelLiu good catch. Thanks. back to the drawing board. :) I'll get it. lol

Comment: @MichaelLiu, fixed. Not as simple as yours. Will be adding your answer to my string extensions tool belt. Thanks

Comment: You got my +1. I like how you handle digits too.

Answer (score 1):

This approach is similar to @Gabor's, with some safeguards and optimizations.  Though admittedly nowhere near as compact as @MichaelLiunot's regex solution, it should be much faster.  I've tested it against all of the examples given thus far.

```
public static string ToSentence(this string value)
{
    if (value == null) return value;
    int length = value.Length;
    if (length <= 1) return value;

    var sb = new StringBuilder(value[0].ToString(), length);
    char currentChar;

    for (int ubound = length - 2, i = 1; i <= ubound; ++i)
    {
        currentChar = value[i];
        if (Char.IsUpper(currentChar) && (Char.IsLower(value[i - 1]) || Char.IsLower(value[i + 1])))
            sb.Append(' ');
        sb.Append(currentChar);
    }
    currentChar = value[length - 1];
    if (Char.IsUpper(currentChar) && Char.IsLower(value[length - 2]))
        sb.Append(' ');
    sb.Append(currentChar);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: One more case to consider: If the last word is a single uppercase letter, then a space should be inserted before it. (Also, you can simplify the `Append` calls by removing the `1`s.)

Comment: Good catch; updated my answer.  The `1`s in the call to `Append` are intentional; it's a micro-optimization.  The `Append(char)` overload ultimately calls the `Append(char,int)` overload.  By using the latter directly, I can remove the overhead incurred by calling the prior.

Comment: Now an exception is thrown if the input is a single uppercase letter. [`Append(char)`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs.html#a2e7c78d85807da5) only calls the `Append(char, int)` overload if there's no room in the current buffer. I think the former should be faster in the common case.

Comment: I've updated my answer with additional safeguards. Regarding `Append` overloads, you are correct about the behavior; more specifically, in the case of this method, the `Append(char)` overload is indeed faster. I'd made an assumption about `Append(char,int)`'s performance. Point well made.